# Inno Setup : Exclude a directory and its files also

Tags: inno-setup

I use the "Exclude" flag in Inno Setup in order to exclude from installation a subdirectory name "Bin32" or "Bin64" depending on the user's architecture.

All I want is to NOT install the useless folder and ALL its files and subdirectories as well.

Here are my current rules:

```
[Files]
Source: "Z:\Work\temp\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

; Exclude
Source: "*"; Excludes: "\Bin64"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: recursesubdirs; Check: not Is64BitInstallMode
Source: "*"; Excludes: "\Bin32"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: recursesubdirs; Check: Is64BitInstallMode
```

First, I don't quite understand what the "*" stands for at the beginning of the excluded rules ?
Second, it works fine with all subdirectories inside Bin32/64 folder but the files are still been installed and I can't figure out a way to not install them...

Thx.

Comment: Yes I have... Does not help :(

Comment: maybe try with Bin64 instead of \Bin64 ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each entry is a single operation and is not effected by any other entry. With that in mind, this is what happens:

1. The first line installs everying from `z:\work\temp`.
2. The 2nd line, if in 32-bit mode, installs everything from `SourceDir` except `\Bin64`
3. The 3rd line, if in 64-bit mode, installs everything from `SourceDir` except `\Bin32`

I expect that your `SourceDir` (the script path if not specified) is the same as `Z:\Work\Temp` and as such, you essentially end up with everything installed anyway.

If you duplicate the first entry, and move the `Excludes` (without the \ prefix) and `Check` parameters onto it, it should work as you require:

```
[Files]
Source: "Z:\Work\temp\*"; Excludes: "Bin64"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Check: not Is64BitInstallMode
Source: "Z:\Work\temp\*"; Excludes: "Bin32"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Check: Is64BitInstallMode
```

Comment: I have tried every combination I can think of to exclude a folder, and it doesn't work. Looks like I have to file a bug report. Version 5.6.1.

Comment: @BentTranberg It seems like I have the same problem. Any news on that problem?

Comment: @jaba - no. In my case I fixed it by deleting unwanted folders in my build script, before it runs the Inno Setup script.