# Inno Setup Exclude only a subdirectory in tree root, but not all other subdirectories within the tree with the same name

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have this in my `[Files]` header:

```
[Files]
Source: "{#PathToRepoRoot}\Development\aaa\bbb\libs\MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}";  \
    Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "{#PathToRepoRoot}\Development\aaa\bbb\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Excludes: "*.pyc, {#PathToRepoRoot}\Development\aaa\bbb\Build"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

It is supposed to exclude all files from the `Build` folder but for some reason it doesn't. I have tried changing `bbb\*` to `bbb\` and `bbb` but it doesn't help. I also took a look at [Inno Setup : Exclude a directory and its files also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645269/inno-setup-exclude-a-directory-and-its-files-also) but this didn't help. The strange thing is that the `.pyc` files are being excluded

I found out that doing `Excludes: "*.pyc, Build";` does what I want. From what I understand this will exclude all files that are named `Build`. In my case this is not a problem since I only have one such file. But I do prefer a more specific exclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the masks in the [`Excludes` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=Excludes) are evaluated against a relative path starting from the root folder (`{#PathToRepoRoot}\Development\aaa\bbb`). So you want to match just `Build`.

But indeed, if you use `Build` only as an exclude mask, it would exclude all `Build` files and folders anywhere in the tree, as the mask is matched against the end of the (relative) path by default. Prepend the mask with a backslash to tell Inno Setup to evaluate it against the beginning of the (relative) path:

```
Excludes: \Build
```